# $p$ is prime and $a\in \mathbb Z$ Prove that this set is a complete residue system $\bmod p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

if $p$ is prime and $a\in \mathbb Z$ such that $p\nmid a$, Show that the set
$$ R=\{0,a,2a,3a,...,(p-1)a\}$$

Is a complete residue system modulo $p$.

This problem is from my textbook.

**My attempt:**

I think that the best way to prove it it's by contradiction, so let $x,y \in R$ such that :
$$x\ne y, x\equiv y \pmod p$$

and we gonna prove that it's impossible that $x,y\in R$ and $x\equiv y \pmod p$... But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $a$ is missing. Let $x=k_1a,y=k_2a$ where $k_i\in\{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$. Then $k_1-k_2\in\{-(p-1),...,-1,0,1,2,...,p-1\}$.

$p|(x-y)\implies p|(k_1-k_2)a$ and since $p\nmid a$, it must be that $p|(k_1-k_2)$. So $k_1-k_2=0$. Thus $x=y$.

Comment: why $k_1-k_2 = 0$

Comment: Because $0$ is the only value in $\{-(p-1),...,-1,0,1,...,p-1\}$ that is divisible by $p$.

Comment: and why $p\mid x-y$

Comment: Well you assumed $x\equiv y\mod p$.

Comment: yeah I forgot, thank you